# How to check which message is sent and return reply accordingly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js

I'm building a discord bot and I want the bot to reply based on what input I give. My JSON file looks like this.

```
const greetings = [
    {
        id: 1,
        received: [
            "Hi",
            "Hi there",
            "Hello",
            "Hey",
            "Hey there"
        ],
        reply: "Hi there"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        recived: [
            "Wassup",
            "Sup"
        ],
        reply: "Nothing much. Wassup",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        received: [
            "How are you doing",
            "How are you doing?",
            "How have you been doing",
            "How have you been doing?",
        ],
        reply: "I'm good. And I hope you're doing well too",
    },
];
```

When I send a message like Hi or Hello there, I want it to respond with Hi there. And when I send a message like How are you doing, it should reply with I'm good. And I hope you're doing well too.

How do I check which message is sent and return the appropriate reply?

Comment: This data structure can become inefficient. I suggest looking into tries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie . This could also help you when the received message doesn't perfectly match what you have in your data file if you implement a levenshtein distance algorithm.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I checked through each element of the received array for each element in the greetings array using a nested for loop, and it worked.

Comment: @VineethBV you don't need to iterate each element. You can use `Array.find` instead. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.find` to find an array item with its value and `Array.some` to check if it exists.

The code would be:

```js
if (greetings.some(x => x.received.includes(message.content))) {
  message.channel.send(greetings.find(x => x.received.includes(message.content)).reply);
})
```